# Fetching backend user in TYPO3 v9 not possible

Tags: typo3, fetch

I worked with older TYPO3 versions (< v9)

I am not able to fetch the logged in backend user in my frontend extension.
In earlier TYPO3 versions I was able to do that.

Now when I logged in in TYPO3 backend and ask for it now it won't work anymore.

My approach is:

```
$context = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class);
$be_username = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('backend.user', 'username');
```

I am getting an empty string. I know that backend user might be not available for FE.
But I need to check on him.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if a Backend user is currently logged in, then the code is exactly right (you don't even need to check on the username).

```
$context = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class);
$isLoggedIn = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('backend.user', 'isLoggedIn');
```

However, if you do this in your extension in a Plugin, that is cacheable ("USER" cObject, or a "non-cacheable action" in an Extbase Plugin), this information could be cached, which can lead to serious! sideffects.

In general, you should only check for a backend user in Frontend-related events, PSR-15 middlewares or hooks from TSFE, not in plugins/cObjects etc. unless you really know what you are doing.

All the best,
Benni-

Comment: Well, I checked the code in TYPO3 version 9.5.9, Its return username for me. Don't know what's wrong with his case.

Comment: @Benni: Thanks, Can you give me a short example how to do that with hooks from TSFE?

Comment: @user3332010 are you using an Extbase plugin? Can you share your `ext_localconf.php` where you register your actions?